# Cannot install Nexus 5 drivers on Windows Vista 32-bit

Tags: windows-vista, drivers, android

I Cannot install Nexus 5 drivers on Windows Vista 32-bit. Developer options are set on my Nexus 5. Followed steps here http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#WinVista Could not detect the driver.

> C:\Users\Me\development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

In SDK Manager, verified that latest drivers are downloaded. ADT version is 20140702

I also tried this advice unsuccessfully https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392226/nexus-5-will-not-show-in-eclipse

Comment: why was this question down voted?

Comment: no idea, this happens very often. +1 to stop this. Try to shorten the path to the drivers like C:\driver

Comment: thanks! the path is what I browsed to, and is the correct path in android

Comment: yes, but it maybe too long in Windows (MAX_PATH is 260 in Windows). So try a shorter path.

Comment: If you read the instructions on the android site, it asks you to browse to the folder. refer the link in the post. and this fits on one line, so is definitely less than 80 chars.